# WPF ItemsControl and binding to self

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have an items control bound to a collection of type 'TypeA'. This type 'TypeA' has a collection of type 'TypeB'.

In the items control `dataTemplate`, I have a `datagrid` which displays a row for each item of the `TypeB` collection and for each row one column displaying the value of the variable 'VariableOfTypeB'.

It works fine.

Now, I would like to display another `datagrid` below which binds to the current item of the collection of type 'TypeA' and which would display the value of the variable 'VariableOfTypeA'. This I cannot seem to achieve.

I can access 'VariableOfTypeA' outside of the `datagrid`, in a label for instance.

Would you have any tip please?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TypeACollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TypeBCollection}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto"
                                                Binding="{Binding VariableOfTypeB />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <!-- cannot make this work -->
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto"
                                                Binding="{Binding VariableOfTypeA />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Not sure what it has to do with anything. Please read the question again: I want to bind the datagrid with the current item of TypeA. I can access it fine outside of the datagrid.

Comment: Again, you do not understand the question. Thanks for taking the time to reply though.

Comment: The past tense (and past participle) of _to bind_ is _bound_. It's _"

I have an items control **bound** (or **that binds**) to a collection"_. _binded_  doesn't exist. I read it too often and it always feels disturbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemsControl` does not have a `SelectedItem` which is what you are looking for in a sense.

You would be better suited to use a `DataGrid` or `ListView` which has a selected row property (of/from your A collection) which then could be bound to in the subgrid to show the alternate information.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, thanks for taking the time to reply OmegaMan. I am going to find another way to achieve this result.